# Prove or disprove $\exists x \in A (P(x)) \lor \exists x \in B (Q(x)) \equiv \exists x \in A \cup B (P(x) \lor Q(x))$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I want to know if $$\exists x \in A (P(x)) \lor \exists x \in B (Q(x)) \equiv \exists x \in A \cup B (P(x) \lor Q(x)).$$

The [$\Rightarrow$] was straightforward, but I'm a little bit confused when proving [$\Leftarrow$].

**Proof sketch:**

[$\Rightarrow$] Suppose $\exists x \in A (P(x)) \lor \exists x \in B (Q(x))$.

Case 1:
If $\exists x \in A (P(x))$, then there is some $x_0 \in A$ such that $P(x_0)$. Then $x_0 \in A \cup B$. Since $P(x_0)$ is true, we are done.

Case 2:
If $\exists x \in B (Q(x))$, then there is some $x_0 \in B$ such that $Q(x_0)$. Then $x_0 \in B \cup A$. Since $Q(x_0)$ is true, we are done.

[$\Leftarrow$] Suppose $\exists x \in A \cup B (P(x) \lor Q(x))$. Then there exists $x_0 \in A \cup B$.

Case 1: If $x_0 \in A$, then $P(x_0) \lor Q(x_0)$. In case $P(x_0)$ is true, we are done. Otherwise, what if $Q(x_0)$? Since in this case $x_0 \in A$, I can't conclude the goal is true, right?

Case 2: If $x_0 \in B$, then $P(x_0) \lor Q(x_0)$. Analogous to case 1.

Does it mean the equivalence is false, or am I missing something?

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: By contemplating where you encountered trouble in the right-to-left proof, you can concoct a counterexample where the universe of discourse has just two elements. (If $A$ or $B$ is allowed to be empty, you can get it down to just oneelement.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right to left direction of the equivalence is false. E.g., take $A = \{x \in \Bbb{Z} \mid x > 0\}$, $B = \{x \in \Bbb{Z} \mid x < 0\}$, $P(x) \equiv x = -1$, $Q(x) \equiv x = 1$, then $\exists x \in A (P(x)) \lor \exists x \in B (Q(x))$ is false, but $\exists x \in A \cup B (P(x) \lor Q(x))$ is true.